# what if I have duplicate nuget packages in multiple sources?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

If I have 2 sources in my nuget file (internal sources) and in both of those sources I have a package with the same name and version which source will nuget pull the package from? Will it be the source listed first?

It normally wouldnt matter but lets say I have two packages with the exact same name and version but the package itself is actually different.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "2 sources"? Show an example, please. Packages on NuGet.org must have a unique package ID, so it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: These are internal packages not public

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "internal"? Be specific.

Comment: You cannot rely on the order of the NuGet package sources. With older NuGet 2 the package sources were tried in order but with NuGet 3 and above they are tried in parallel so you cannot rely on the ordering.

Comment: The question seems quite clear. The guidance I've seen is to have only one active package source at once or you will get non-deterministic behavior. So if you are using a private repository, that repository will need to contain all of your needed packages or it will need to pass through to an upstream source.

Comment: Looks like package source mapping could also help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what if I have duplicate nuget packages in multiple sources?

When you open NuGet Package Manager setting, Tools->Options->NuGet Packager Manager->Package Source, you will notice that there are up and down arrows for package source:

[image]

NuGet Package Manager will **give priority** to **search** package in the top of the package source list.

**However, this priority can easily be broken by order of the quickest response and different version**. Just like Matt said "*NuGet 3 and above they are tried in parallel*". So when one of your package source reacts significantly faster than others, the priority will be broken, the quickest response package source will be used.

Besides, priority will given to package sources which contain a higher version of the package.

As suggestion, since your packages itself are actually different, I suggest you can give them different name or different version.